# What are themes when it comes to Material UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying understand what exactly themes are and what they're trying to represent.  I've read the docs but it still doesn't make sense to me.

For example, below is a piece of code of what I'm referring to.

I just want to know what `theme` is supposed to represent, where it's coming from and why it's used.

```
const styles = theme => ({
root: {
    display: 'flex',
},

toolbar: {
    paddingRight: 24, // keep right padding when drawer closed
},

toolbarIcon: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    padding: '0 8px',
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
},
});
```

Comment: Your code has created a function names `styles` which accepts a `theme` argument and returns an object. MaterialUI calls `styles(defaultTheme)`, the result being your style object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Material-UI documentation covers this pretty thoroughly, but there are a few different parts of the documentation necessary to understand the code you posted.

- https://material-ui.com/customization/themes/

  - This is the main documentation on themes
- https://material-ui.com/customization/css-in-js/

  - You need to understand how the CSS-in-JS aspects work to understand how the `styles` variable would be used
- https://material-ui.com/customization/css-in-js/#withstyles-styles-options-higher-order-component

  - The `withStyles` function in particular is what would generally receive the `styles` variable as a parameter and then take care of injecting the theme.
- https://material-ui.com/customization/themes/#createmuitheme-options-theme

  - This part describes creating a theme.
- https://material-ui.com/customization/themes/#muithemeprovider

  - This describes how to provide a custom theme to your app (which would then automatically be injected where necessary by Material-UI when you use its components or methods like `withStyles`), but Material-UI automatically provides a default theme that is in play if you haven't provided a custom one.

As far as why the theme is used, the documentation covers this some, but one use case is controlling color schemes. For instance, if you have a multi-tenant application (one code base used for multiple clients), you may want to support using colors that are specific to each client's branding. Themes provide a way of changing colors, fonts, and other look-and-feel aspects dynamically by simply providing a different theme at the root of your app. In the particular example you posted, the theme is being used to pull in some CSS for the look of toolbars that is included in Material-UI's default theme but which could be overridden in a custom theme.

Here is the Material-UI code that is responsible for the defaults for `theme.mixins.toolbar`: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/styles/createMixins.js

And here is the relevant excerpt from that code:

```
toolbar: {
      minHeight: 56,
      [`${breakpoints.up('xs')} and (orientation: landscape)`]: {
        minHeight: 48,
      },
      [breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
        minHeight: 64,
      },
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can (optionally) create your own theme trough `createMuiTheme`.
These themes and its variables (colours, default, spacings or whatever you desire) can be accessed in your styles which you add in your withstyles trough the theme arguement.

Great stuff to have the same paddings or margins anywhere for example.